# How do I disable onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave events based on screen width?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I'm using React with styled-components, so let's say I have a div like this:

```js
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`
```

```html
return (
  <Container
    onMouseEnter{() => alert("foo")}
    onMouseLeave{() => alert("bar")}
  >
    Content
  </Container>
)
```

How do I disable these alerts (*onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave* events) when the device screen width is less than 700px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Window.matchMedia()

```
if ( window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)').matches ) {
   // your function executed below 700px window width
}
```